# Set SVN bugtraq properties recursively on all folders with local working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to implement the [TSVN Bugtraq](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) properties on a repository.  However, the repository is very large, so I don't want to have to download the entire thing to a working copy in order to set those properties.  I'd prefer to set them server-side.

My plan was to do something like this:

```
svn propset -R propname value svn://myrepo.path/
```

But that gives me this error:

```
svn: E200009: Targets must be working copy paths
```

In doing some reading, apparently svn propset only works on local working copies.

**Is there any way to do a recursive propset on an entire repo without having to download the full repo to a working copy?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion bugtraq property, as it happens, is unique: it was an inherited property prior to 1.8! So in version 1.7 you need only check out the root level folder--with no children--and apply the property. Once that is done you can even confirm that it works before you commit the property change.

I have written about this extensively in [part 8](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-8-log-messages/) of my **TortoiseSVN and Subversion Cookbook**, on Simple-Talk.com.

Comment: I have one repo on 1.6.  Do you happen to know if this would also work with 1.6 or is 1.7 when it was added as an inherited property?

Comment: I do not know if it will work in 1.6--try it and see. (Remember you do not need to commit to check this.)

Comment: It did work just fine.  I'm guessing it more depends on the Tortoise client version as opposed to the repo version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Subversion 1.8 got concept of "[Inherited Properties](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/InheritedProperties)", now you can define property only in tree-root

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately my repo is on 1.7 at the moment.  So hopefully there is another option out there...